# Pandas groupBy multiple columns and aggregation

Tags: python, pandas

In dataframe have 4 columns col_A,col_B,col_C,col_D.Need to group the columns(col_A,col_B,col_C) and aggregate mean by col_D. Below is the code snippet I tried and it worked

`df.groupby(['col_A','col_B','col_C']).agg({'col_D':'mean'}).reset_index()`

But in addition to the above result, also require the group by count of ('col_A','col_B','col_C') along with aggregation. Any help on this please.

Comment: `df.groupby(['col_A','col_B','col_C'])['col_D'].agg(['mean', 'count']).reset_index()`?

Comment: as_index can be set to False; negates the reset index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Named Aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation):

```py
result = (
    df.groupby(['col_A', 'col_B', 'col_C'], as_index=False)
      .agg(mean=('col_D', 'mean'), count=('col_D', 'count'))
)
```

For the `count` columns, you have 2 choices in choosing the aggregate function:

- `count=('col_D', 'count')` will ignore any NaN value in `col_D`
- `count=('col_D', 'size')` will include NaN values in `col_D`